# Angular Material Datepicker: Support of BCE Dates and Calendars

Tags: angular, datepicker, calendar, angular-material

I am getting familiar with Angular Material's Datepicker (https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview).

For my use case, I need the following features:

- support of dates Before Christ (BC) / Before Common Era (BCE)
- support of other calendar formats besides Gregorian (e.g., Julian calendar), including automatic conversion of the selected date when changing the calendar
- support of precision: day, month, year

In our old GUI, we provided our own implementation of a date picker, applying calculations based on Julian Day Numbers (https://github.com/dhlab-basel/Knora/blob/develop/salsah/src/public/js/datehelpers.js, https://github.com/dhlab-basel/Knora/blob/develop/salsah/src/public/js/jquery.dateobj.js). However, the code was based on jQuery and is going to be replaced by the new Angular based GUI. I also admit that it is hard to understand.

I would be glad for any advice of how to support historical dates with Angular Material!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, clearly Angular Material doesn't support this and will likely never support it. You could look on https://www.npmjs.com/ to see if there are any other 3rd party calendars that meet your needs (I didn't find anything when I did a quick search), so unfortunately you'll probably need to code all that yourself.

Comment: I think the GUI-component should be separated from the underlying calculations needed. I found some libraries for date calculations on npmjs.com (e.g., https://www.npmjs.com/package/moonbeams) that could be used. Implementing these algorithms yourself would be a pain (for example, the year 0 question: http://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/calendar/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the topic is discussed here: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2519

The Angular Material2 Datepicker UI is separated from an abstract class `DateAdapter` that can be implemented for different calendar libraries (the JS native Date object and the Moment JS library).

I have started an own repo that supports calendar conversions (https://github.com/dhlab-basel/JDNConvertibleCalendar) and provided an implementation of `DateAdapter` (https://github.com/dhlab-basel/JDNConvertibleCalendarDateAdapter). Soon it should be possible to switch between Gregorian and Julian calendar dates using the Angular Material2 Datepicker.